# Is this the nimitta?

Tags: nimitta

During my sit today I remembered that on my last retreat two weeks ago I kept seeing this wooden box. It was like I was breathing into it. I wasnt sure at the time what it was. I asked the teacher but they didn't mention anything about nimitta but I just realised during my sit today that this was probably what it was.

Comment: Based on the way the question is phrased, I expect that the answers would be pretty much opinion-based. One person may have the opinion that the wooden box is a nimitta. Another person may have the opinion that it's your imagination. How could any of those two answers be judged as the right one? They would only each present a valid opinion. Please see "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)". After you have updated the question, we may reopen it.

Comment: Ok. I would say to describe about this nimitta with more information, that way one can decide if it was actual nimitta or your imagination. That's because actual nimitta has some special properties. Update your question with this information.

Comment: Actual nimitta has some special properties. If it was actual nimitta, mind should just see only that. No arguments, divinations, but just stillness. Like one's mind become stoned.